# Angularjs getting different response format of API in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement $localforage in angularjs but when i am getting the response from $localstorage the format is weird, it's returning a different format on Chrome and Firefox.

Correct response from API:
Object {rcode: 200, data: Array[15], extra: null, success: true, error: null}

In chrome its returning exact same format which is need as above but when I am trying on firefox its returning only "data" part of api response.

Can any one guide how can i resolve this or should I need to handle the response as per browser.

Comment: Can you share both responses

Comment: In Chrome :

log >>>getData method
 Object {rcode: 200, data: Array[15], extra: null, success: true, error: null}



In Firefox :


log >>>getData method
 [Object { login_id="test168168",  type="first_party",  nfo={...}}]

Comment: In Firefox : log >>>getData method [Object { login_id="test168168", type="first_party", nfo={...}}]